# Как в один объект добавлять множество других объектов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! У меня есть пустой массив, мне нужно добавить в него несколько других объектов с одинаковыми ключами, Как это можно сделать?
Например, при смене значения name мне нужно создать новый объект и поместить его в объект obj. Вот пример моего кода.

```
var obj = {};
for (var key in obj) {
  if (this.obj['name'] !== newObj['name']) {
    console.log("NOT THE SAME");
  }
  if (!(key in obj)) {
    obj[key] = newObj[key];
  } else {
    obj[key] = arr[key] += newObj[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: предоставленный кусок ничего не делает, так как в obj нет ключей - внутрь цикла не зайдет

Comment: Приведи пример начальных данных и конечных. сейчас непонятно что именно ты хочешь получить